# Matlab: Delete duplicate table entries on multiple columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, duplicates

For example: I have the following table

```
table=[1,2,2; 4,5,6; 7,8,9; 1,2,2; 5,5,2]
```

Is it possible to delete a duplicate row if both column 2 and 3 are identical? For the example this would result in:

```
table=[1,2,2; 4,5,6; 7,8,9; 5,5,2]
```

In this case I just want to delete the 4th row. Not the 5th because only the 3th column is identical to the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
[~, ind] = unique(table(:, [2 3]), 'rows');
table = table(ind,:);
```

Comment: Hello Luis, Thanks for your answer. I have tried this ( [~,I] = unique(tabel1(:,2)) ). Identical to your solution. But the problem is that I just can delete on one row and not on two. Or at least I am not capable.

Comment: I hadn't read your question correctly. Please see edited answer

Comment: Thanks, I was fiddling with the brackets but i could not find the correct notation.